# Auto Delete Rows in a DataGridView with a loop"Hard Coding"

Tags: c#, datagridview, delete-row

Ok , I have used and edited my cells and rows from a data grid view and now I want to delete some Rows. I have tried the Remove and RemoveAt methods but it won't work. Gives me index error. Have a look at the code .

```
for (z = 0; z < counterpraxeis; z++)
{
    this.dataGridView3.Rows.Remove(dataGridView3.Rows[z]);
}
```

So i want to delete the first Rows equal to counterpraxeis. any help ? and one more question . When the first , let's say 5 rows are deleted , does the index updates automatically ?

Comment: can you post the error message?...

Comment: index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: use `foreach` in such cases.

Comment: does this :  dataGridView3.Rows.Remove(dataGridView3.Rows[0]); Removes the first line existing in the DGV ?

Comment: `RemoveAt(this.dataGridView3.SelectedRows[0].Index);` try this.